# Checking exactness of etale sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $0 \rightarrow F \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 0$ be sequence of sheaves of etale sheaves on $X_{et}$ ($X$ is a scheme). To prove they are exact, one way is show that $0 \rightarrow F_{\bar{x}} \rightarrow G_{\bar{x}} \rightarrow H_{\bar{x}} \rightarrow 0$ for every geometric point $\bar{x} \rightarrow X.$ 
 But in many places it is claimed, it is enough to show that sequence is exact for any $U \rightarrow X$ in $X_{et}$, when restricted to $U_{zar}$.

For example, in Proposition 14.1.1 (Page 83) [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bruno.klingler/cours/Weil.pdf).

Why is it so?

Comment: Can you point out which part you're having trouble with? Is it right exactness, left, or middle?

Comment: Here is what I tought, suppose the sequence is exact for $U_{zar}$. Then we get the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow F(U) \rightarrow G(U) \rightarrow H(U)$ since section functor is left exact. Now, that limits over all etale neighbourhoods of $\bar{x}$, we get $0 \rightarrow F_{\bar{x}} \rightarrow G_{\bar{x}} \rightarrow H_{\bar{x}}$ so, this imples $0 \rightarrow F \rightarrow G \rightarrow H $. So, I guess it is the right exactness I am having difficulty with.

Comment: So now, suppose that $s\in H(U)$ for some $U\to X$ in the etale site of $X$. Then, since $F\mid_{U_\text{zar}}\to H\mid_{U_\text{zar}}$ is surjective we know that there is some open cover $V_i\subseteq U$ such that $s\mid_{V_i}$ is in the image of $F(V_i)$. But, then evidently the composition $\{\bigsqcup_i V_i\to U\}$ is a cover of $U$ in $X_{\mathrm{et}}$ such that $s\mid_{ \bigsqcup_i V_i}$ is in the image of $F\left(\bigsqcup_i V_i\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex. I got it now.